# No-slip condition when one fluid flows through another

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What sort of no-slip zone is in place when liquid water flows from a faucet through air at room temperature? Does the water drag a layer of air molecules along with it?

Answer (score 1):

Do an experiment.  Five gallon bucket, garden hose on full, nothing attached to its far end.  Lower its far end normal to the the bottom of the bucket.  You can feel the reaction force pushing upward...until you almost touch the bottom.  The push abruptly changes to suction though the water continues to gush from the open end through the now narrow gap.  Trace the flows.

Comment: I'll certainly give it a go. I'll post again once it's been completed.